# TSQL: How to use charindex ? - Finding a specific word in a variable string between specific characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this string: `'Level 1 - Level 2 - Level 3 - Level 4 - Level 5 - Level 6 - Level 7'`

I would like to get the Level 6 word and level 5 word apart. I did try to google a few things, but they are not really helping me in this case. Because the levels will have different words and such, so it will be different lengths.

I tried the following but I know this will only select the first word between these: '-' '-'

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @text = 'Level 1 - Level 2 - Level 3 - Level 4 - Level 5 - Level 6 - Level 7'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@text,CHARINDEX('-',@text)+1, CHARINDEX('-',@text,CHARINDEX('-',@text)+1) -CHARINDEX('-',@text)-1) as Level 6
```

Can anyone of you help me on the right path ?

I am currently still new to using `CHARINDEX`.

Comment: You should strive to stop using delimited strings altogether. Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f5363872489688c3a2c09b8a781a5597)

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @L5 INT
DECLARE @L6 INT

SET @text = 'Level 1 - Level 2 - Level 3 - Level 4 - Level 5 - Level 6 - Level 7'

SELECT 
@L5 = CHARINDEX('-',@text,CHARINDEX('-',@text,CHARINDEX('-',@text,CHARINDEX('-',@text,1)+1)+1)+1),
@L6 = CHARINDEX('-',@text,CHARINDEX('-',@text,CHARINDEX('-',@text,CHARINDEX('-',@text,CHARINDEX('-',@text,1)+1)+1)+1)+1)

SELECT @L5,@l6,
LEFT(RIGHT(@text,LEN(@text)-@L5),CHARINDEX('-',RIGHT(@text,LEN(@text)-@L5))-1),
LEFT(RIGHT(@text,LEN(@text)-@L6),CHARINDEX('-',RIGHT(@text,LEN(@text)-@L6))-1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much mkRabbani, this will work perfectly.

Thank you for your quick response and help, I appreacite it.

Comment: You are most welcome @WimpieNorman. You can also put an up vote if it really helped :)